# replace navigation menu with custom div (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

How can I replace the menu in my wordpress theme with a different div - but only on a certain page of my site?

Here's what it says in themes.php

```
<div class="frame">

<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-main','sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_id' => 'main-nav-menu',  'fallback_cb' => false ) ); ?>

</div>
```

I need something to say instead something like:

```
<div class="frame">

//if the page id=1545, then show this div:
<div id="my-new-div">Slogan goes here</div>

//else
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-main','sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_id' => 'main-nav-menu',  'fallback_cb' => false ) ); ?>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get the job done:

```
<?php $page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id     = get_queried_object_id(); ?>

<div class="frame">

<?php if ($page_id == 1545): ?>

    <div id="my-new-div">Slogan goes here</div>

<?php else: ?>

    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-main','sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_id' => 'main-nav-menu',  'fallback_cb' => false ) ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>


</div>
```

Fixed a small issue with the php tags

Comment: Thanks for the response!  It doesn't seem to be working though. The nav is still there, but it prints the text "$page_object = get_queried_object(); $page_id = get_queried_object_id();" on top of the nav.